# Inherit and Override CSS

Tags: css

I've been using twitter-bootstrap CSS for a while. The reason I use it is because I do not know much about CSS. Now in my code often I use `style` on element which is already assigned to a class. Example:

```
<div style="background-color: white" class="thumbnail"></div>
```

The above code does not look nice. The class may already have a background-color property. What is the most efficient way to simplify it ?

Comment: "The class may already have a background-color property." It will override it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `.thumbnail` class at the end of the css where it exists and override it with the values you want. Thats it.

**For Instance,**

```
   ..

   ..

   ..

    .thumbnail{
         background-color: white
    }
```

Hope this helps.